# OpenCV iOS - Not the same result on simulator and on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, simulator, perspective

I have a problem with cropping image using OpenCV library on a real iPhone.

I have an image with selected area and I'd like to apply a perspective transform on the image with this area. This works fine on the simulator but on the iphone the new image isn't map to rectangle and the new image has also blue color.

Here is my code :

```
+ (IplImage *)CreateIplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    // Getting CGImage from UIImage
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    // Creating temporal IplImage for drawing
    IplImage *iplimage = cvCreateImage(
                                       cvSize(image.size.width,image.size.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4
                                       );
    // Creating CGContext for temporal IplImage
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                    iplimage->imageData, iplimage->width, iplimage->height,
                                                    iplimage->depth, iplimage->widthStep,
                                                    colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault
                                                    );
    // Drawing CGImage to CGContext
    CGContextDrawImage(
                       contextRef,
                       CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height),
                       imageRef
                       );
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Creating result IplImage
    IplImage *ret = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iplimage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvCvtColor(iplimage, ret, CV_RGBA2BGR);
    cvReleaseImage(&iplimage);

    return ret;
}

+ (UIImage *)UIImageFromIplImage:(IplImage *)img {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Creating result IplImage
    IplImage *image = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
    cvCvtColor(img, image, CV_BGR2RGBA);

    // Allocating the buffer for CGImage
    NSData *data =
    [NSData dataWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];
    CGDataProviderRef provider =
    CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    // Creating CGImage from chunk of IplImage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(
                                        image->width, image->height,
                                        image->depth, image->depth * image->nChannels, image->widthStep,
                                        colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                        provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                        );

    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return ret;
}

+ (UIImage *)perspectiveTransform: (UIImage*) originalImage :(CGFloat) h :(CGFloat) w :(CGPoint) point1 :(CGPoint) point2 :(CGPoint) point3 :(CGPoint) point4
{

    CvPoint2D32f srcQuad[4];

    srcQuad[0].x = point1.x;
    srcQuad[0].y = point1.y;
    srcQuad[1].x = point2.x;
    srcQuad[1].y = point2.y;
    srcQuad[2].x = point3.x;
    srcQuad[2].y = point3.y;
    srcQuad[3].x = point4.x;
    srcQuad[3].y = point4.y;

    IplImage *src = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:originalImage];

    IplImage *dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),
                                  src->depth,
                                  src->nChannels);

    cvZero(dst);

    CGFloat width = src->width;
    CGFloat height = src->height;

    CvMat* mmat = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);

    CvPoint2D32f *c1 = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(4 * sizeof(CvPoint2D32f));
    CvPoint2D32f *c2 = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(4 * sizeof(CvPoint2D32f));

    c1[0].x = round((width/w)*srcQuad[0].x);   c1[0].y = round((height/h)*srcQuad[0].y);
    c1[1].x = round((width/w)*srcQuad[1].x);   c1[1].y = round((height/h)*srcQuad[1].y);
    c1[2].x = round((width/w)*srcQuad[2].x);   c1[2].y = round((height/h)*srcQuad[2].y);
    c1[3].x = round((width/w)*srcQuad[3].x);   c1[3].y = round((height/h)*srcQuad[3].y);

    c2[0].x = 0;            c2[0].y = 0;
    c2[1].x = width - 1;    c2[1].y = 0;
    c2[2].x = 0;            c2[2].y = height - 1;
    c2[3].x = width - 1;    c2[3].y = height - 1;

    mmat = cvGetPerspectiveTransform(c1, c2, mmat);
    free(c1);
    free(c2);

    cvWarpPerspective(src, dst, mmat, CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cvScalarAll(0));

    cvReleaseImage(&src);
    cvReleaseMat(&mmat);

    UIImage *newImage = [self UIImageFromIplImage:dst];
    cvReleaseImage(&dst);

    return newImage;
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is it possible that `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault` might map to a different default byte order in the Simulator vs. on the device? Would explicitly specifying `kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little` or something like it help with the colorspace issues here?

Comment: It seemed like a good idea but unfortunately, it doesn't work for kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little and kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big :-(